# VBA: Delimiters for Input keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to parse each line of a text file stored in filepath into my string array. However, it appears that I'm delimited by characters other than the newline character (for example, commas). Is there a way of parsing with new line characters exclusively? Thanks in advance for your guidance.

```
'Open filepath For Input As #1

    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Input #1, script(numlines)
        numlines = numlines + 1
        If numlines = maxlines Then
            maxlines = maxlines + 100
            ReDim script(maxlines)
        End If
    Loop

    ' Close file
    Close #1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Input #` statement is generally used to read data written with the `Write #` statement. If you just want to read a line of text, you can use [`Line Input #`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264130.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Didn't know VBA that well (let alone I'm rusty at it after shelving it for 2 years). Btw, cool website.